# How to upload documents to CouchDB from Angular using HttpClient

Tags: angular, couchdb, angular7

I set up a new CouchDB on my local computer. When I try to upload new documents to an existing database using HTTP POST method, CouchDB refuses the request and claims it was HTTP OPTIONS method.

**Typescript classes**

My service class looks as follows.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class DbService {

    private static readonly BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:5984/';
    private static readonly ENTRIES_URL = DbService.BASE_URL + 'entries';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    writeEntry(entry: Object): Promise<Object> {
        return this.http.post<Object>(DbService.ENTRIES_URL, entry).toPromise();
    }
}
```

The service is used by the following method, located in a component class.

```
private onEntry(entry: Object): void {
    try {
         console.log('onEntry', entry);
         this.dbService.writeEntry(entry)
             .then(r => console.log(r))
             .catch(e => console.error(e));
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

**What I tried so far**

1. Using Fauxton, I created a new database named *entries*
2. I successfully uploaded new documents to the *entries* database using curl as follows

   ```
   curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST 
   http://127.0.0.1:5984/entries -d '{ "amount": 1 }'
   ```
3. When running the Angular code (ng serve & Chrome Browser)

   - I see the console log info (before service call), followed by the error log. 
     [image: info log] 
     [image: error log]
   - CouchDB logs the following (405 Method not allowed)

     ```
     [notice] 2019-04-09T06:03:26.304000Z couchdb@localhost  00d60c0651 localhost:5984 127.0.0.1 undefined OPTIONS /entries 405 ok 7
     ```

**Last Attempt**

When changing my service method as follows, the POST method is finally carried on to the wire but CouchDB logs an HTTP 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

```
writeEntry(entry: Object): Promise<Object> {
    const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.set('Accept', 'application/json');
    httpHeaders.set('Content-type', 'application/json');
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: httpHeaders
    };
    return this.http.post<Object>(DbService.ENTRIES_URL, JSON.stringify(entry), httpOptions).toPromise();
}
```

```
[notice] 2019-04-09T13:35:59.312000Z couchdb@localhost  9910b3c996 localhost:5984 127.0.0.1 undefined POST /entries 415 ok 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might have to do with CORS issues.

Try enabling CORS in the CouchDB HTTP Server: https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/config/http.html#config-cors

This feature was built in with https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-431

Comment: It now works after defining [cors] in etc\local.ini and no longer stringify the submitted JSON object, thanks for your help!

[cors]\n
origins = *
methods = GET,POST,PUT
credentials = false