# CouchDB authentication ,CORS issue

Tags: authentication, couchdb

I get this error when trying to authenticate :

> Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:5984/r/' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

This is my code:

```
var rdb = new PouchDB('localhost:5984/r', 
                      { fetch: function (url, opts) { 
                                     opts.headers.set('X-Auth-CouchDB-Roles', '_admin'); 
                                     return PouchDB.fetch(url, opts); 
                                } 
                      });
```

Comment: var rdb = new PouchDB('http://localhost:5984/r', {
    fetch: function (url, opts) {
    opts.headers.set('X-Auth-CouchDB-Roles', '_admin');
    return PouchDB.fetch(url, opts);
    }
});

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: This answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55652448/2358409. Please also consider the comment below the answer.